# Simple C++ isNested boolean method

Tags: c++, stack, boolean

I'm working on creating a C++ method that will use stack to determine if a string of brackets is properly nested.  It compiles okay, but for some reason it always returns true.  Have I made some really obvious logic error or something?  Here's my code:

```
    bool isNested(string target)
    {
        stack<char> brackets;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i > target.length(); i++)
        {
            if (target[i] == '<' || target[i] == '(' || target[i] == '{' || target[i] == '[')
            {
                brackets.push(target[i]);
            }
            else if (target[i] == '>' || target[i] == ')' || target[i] == '}' || target[i] == ']')
            {
                if (brackets.top() == '<' && target[i] == '>')
                {
                    brackets.pop();
                }
                else if (brackets.top() == '(' && target[i] == ')')
                {
                    brackets.pop();
                }
                if (brackets.top() == '{' && target[i] == '}')
                {
                    brackets.pop();
                }
                if (brackets.top() == '[' && target[i] == ']')
                {
                    brackets.pop();
                }
                else
                {
                    brackets.push(target[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (brackets.empty())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For example, I see missing `else` before `if (brackets.top() == '{' ...` and the same with `if (brackets.top() == '['...`. I'd  merge that into one condition with logical OR.

Comment: Vlad is right in his answer. Next time, why don't you try to debug first? Place some breakpoints, and see what the code does step by step! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid condition in the loop

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i > target.length(); i++)
```

As i is initialized by 0

```
unsigned int i = 0;
```

then it can not be greater than target.length()

```
i > target.length();
```

Also the program contains other errors.

For example the meaning of this else statement

```
            else
            {
                brackets.push(target[i]);
            }
```

is not clear.

The function could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

bool isNested( const std::string &target )
{
    const char *open  = "<([{";
    const char *close = ">)]}";
    std::stack<char> st;

    for ( char c : target )
    {
        const char *p;
        if ( ( p = std::strchr( open, c ) ) != nullptr && *p != '\0' )
        {
            st.push( c );
        }
        else if ( ( p = std::strchr( close, c ) ) != nullptr ) 
        {
            if ( st.empty() || open[p - close] != st.top() ) break;
            st.pop();
        }
    }

    return st.empty();
}

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I can't believe I missed that obvious loop condition issue.  :P

Comment: I think I fixed it now.  Tests are looking good.  Thanks again and have an awesome Saturday!  :)